# Persistent lines on screen

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, 2.1-eclair, screen

This morning I noticed my phone has several light grey horizontal lines on the display, that don't go away when I change applications, or restart the phone. They don't rotate when I rotate the display - it reminds me of when we were warned about images "burning" into the display of PCs, hence screensavers.

Last night I went to bed with Winamp running while the phone was charging, and I have noticed it doesn't always seem to go to screensaver/black with Winamp. But the lines don't seem to correspond to anything in the Winamp UI, so...I have no idea.

What else should I try to get rid of these lines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like a hardware problem (assuming the lines extend all the way across the screen).  Could just be a bad connection.

Comment: Agreed, but "just" a bad connection would be pretty hard to fix ;)

Comment: True.  This is where you're glad for (or miss) a warranty.

Comment: I doubt it's burn-in. It might be stuck pixels. But, yes, definitely sounds like hardware.

Comment: It's somewhat been coming and going, which makes a bad connection seem fairly plausible. Boo :(